# YII2 how to update field with query buider

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2, query-builder, insert-update

How can I update the field with query builder in Yii2?

requirement is every transaction from table B table A will automatically update value field: actual and available

Table A

- id
- budget
- actual     // query amount from table b
- available  // value = (budget - actual)

Table B

- id
- amount
- tableA_id

table relation

[image]

here sql query

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT(A.id) AS tableA,
  A.budget AS budget,
  SUM(B.amount) AS actual,
  budget - SUM(B.amount) AS Available
FROM
  tableA AS A
 LEFT JOIN
  TableB AS B
ON
  A.id = B.TableA_id
Group By
 tableA
```

results

[image]

I'm try to learn from https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-dao.md#basic-sql-queries

But i have no idea how to apply SQL to query builder in Yii2 and how to coding or where to put the code in model or controller.

Comment: your sql code seems have some problems  .. 1) why distinct and groyp by??  if you use group by you don't need  distinct  ..

Comment: 2) why you have a non aggregated  column not mentioned  in group by ?  .. this is deprecated  in sql and not allowed  in more recent version of database  eg: mysql 5.7

Comment: 3 ) you can't use alias for column name  inside the select other columns name or calculation  (budget)

Comment: what do want to do you want to `update` records or you want to `select`, your question title is about `update` and you have added the `select` query to be transformed to `QueryBuilder` syntax ?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. my attention is `update` value,sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an easy solution could be based on sql command  (instead of an activeQuery )

```
\Yii::$app->db->createCommand('update TableA A
               inner join (
                select B.TableA_id id
                    , sum(B.amount) Available
                FROM TableB B
                GROUP BY id
               ) T  on A.id =T.id
                AND A.id = :actid
               set budget = budget - T.Available')->bindValue(':actid', $your_id)
->execute();
```

I have refatctored  your code  avoiding the issue in my previous comment

Comment: thanks for the answer. sir

can you tell me where to put your suggestion code.

in _form.php or
or model tableA
or controller tableA

Comment: @ChonjaroenChauynoo  what in your comment is another question  .. you have asked for a SQL update in join solution  .. and i have post an asnwer .. SO in not a coding service and adding question to question is not fair .. so if my answer is right you can mark it as accepted  if my answer  is wrong you can show me the error  .. but not adding question to another question

Comment: @ChonjaroenChauynoo add it inside your model create a function, and call it via action that you are using to update the values in your controller

Comment: @scaisEdge Thank you for your answer again and apologize for mistake. please let me try your statement first, I will update you when it’s done.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Thank you for your suggestion, sir

Comment: @scaisEdge ok i got what i want by follow your statement 
. i write it in model and then use in  controller in action that i want, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a view with the values calculated? So when you access the view the data "actual" and "available" are calculated on the fly.